# Screen reader not reading a <p> tag

Tags: html

Screen reader will read below things.For Example

```
<a> some text </a>
<button> some text </button>
<input type='text' aria-label='Enter search text'>

But my concern is screen reader is not reading 
<p>some text </p>
<span>some text </span>
<div>text</div>
```

Anybody can help me how is it possible ?

Any idea why screen reader is not reading

its reading content only if it have **link or button** .

When i tried with a tag and button  it works, but same not happening with **div and 
span **

Comment: Can anybody help on this

Comment: Not until you do your part to make any kind of help possible in the first place. Go read [ask] and [mcve], please, and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Hey what i need is screen reader will read 
<a href="">some text</a>
<button>button</b>
<input type='text' aria-label='Enter search text'>
the above text all screen reader will read.
But if you go with
<span>text</span><div>text</div> it wont read
Hope you understand

Comment: @CBroe i had changed accordingly .Can you help now?

Comment: @CBroe i hope now you understood my problem